# After EOFException variable=null

Tags: java, variables, client-server, filewriter, eofexception

If I end the client session a EOFException is thrown but I read that this would be normal 
so I just start a new thread with the same functionality but the value of Restaurant=null;
although i wrote it in a .txt file

```
public void run(){

    try {
        ois= new ObjectInputStream(clientside.getInputStream());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        oos = new ObjectOutputStream(clientside.getOutputStream());
    } catch (IOException e3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e3.printStackTrace();
    }

    handlerequest(ois,oos);// exit();
}
```

I dont think that you need the code of my request handler so I wont attach it to reduce code spamming. The method which invokes the following is the requesthandler

```
String tempRestaurant=null;  
try {
    fr = new FileReader("Restaurant.txt");
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
try {
    fr.read(cbuf);
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
tempRestaurant=String.valueOf(cbuf);
System.out.println(tempRestaurant);
try {
    oos.writeObject(tempRestaurant);
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
    try {
    fr.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I´m looking foward to your help pls write if you need more information code etc. :)
This is the Exception below which is thrown after exiting the client

```
java.io.EOFException
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.peekByte(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source)
    at prealphaserverpackage.clientsidethreads.setRestaurant(Serverpart.java:164)
    at prealphaserverpackage.clientsidethreads.handlerequest(Serverpart.java:205)
    at prealphaserverpackage.clientsidethreads.run(Serverpart.java:96)
Exception in thread "Thread-3" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.io.PrintWriter.write(Unknown Source)
    at prealphaserverpackage.clientsidethreads.setRestaurant(Serverpart.java:177)
    at prealphaserverpackage.clientsidethreads.handlerequest(Serverpart.java:205)
    at prealphaserverpackage.clientsidethreads.run(Serverpart.java:96)
```

i added know your code to mine but still is the restaurant null after EOFException has been thrown...

Comment: a more specific and well explained question will be easier to help :)

Comment: you'll get a lot of `NullPointerException` you should try catch the hole block instead of each statement

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Fixed it**

i forgot to add the break line in the switch case szenario in my request handler sry it was my fault... thx for helping me to avoid the EOFException :)

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion:

```
public void run(){
   try(
      ObjectInputStream  ois =
         new ObjectInputStream ( clientside.getInputStream ());
      ObjectOutputStream oos =
         new ObjectOutputStream( clientside.getOutputStream())) {
      handleRequest( ois, oos );
   }
   catch( IOException e ) {
      e.printStackTrace();
   }
}

void handleRequest( ObjectInputStream ois, ObjectOutputStream oos ) {
   try( BufferedReader fr =
           new BufferedReader( new FileReader( "Restaurant.txt" ))) {
      String tempRestaurant = fr.readLine();
      System.out.println( tempRestaurant );
   }
   catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
   }
}
```

try-with-resource close the [Closeable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Closeable.html) declared in `try( )`

Comment: the try-with-resource close helped me to avoid the eofexception thx :)

Answer (score 0):

You can (and often should) put multiple statements inside a try block if they have common exception handling requirements; e.g.

```
try {
    ois = new ObjectInputStream(clientside.getInputStream());
    oos = new ObjectOutputStream(clientside.getOutputStream());
    handlerequest(ois,oos);
} catch (IOException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

But the flip-side is that when you handle an exception, you need to make sure that the exception handler does the right thing.  Printing a stack trace and then continuing as if nothing happened is *rarely* the correct thing to do.  For instance, in your original `run()` method, if there is an `IOException` opening the streams, you code will still attempt to call `handlerequest` ... passing it `ois` and/or `oos` instances that are (probably) `null`.  That is NOT the right thing to do!

Finally, if you are using Java 7, you can catch multiple exceptions in a single handler; e.g.

```
String tempRestaurant=null;  
try {
    fr = new FileReader("Restaurant.txt");
    fr.read(cbuf);
    tempRestaurant = String.valueOf(cbuf);
    System.out.println(tempRestaurant)
    someOtherMethod(); ; 
    oos.writeObject(tempRestaurant);
    fr.close();
} catch (IOException, SomeOtherException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

and you can use "try with resources" to automatically close them when you are done: e.g.

```
String tempRestaurant=null;  
try (FileReader fr = new FileReader("Restaurant.txt")) {
    fr.read(cbuf);
    tempRestaurant = String.valueOf(cbuf);
    System.out.println(tempRestaurant);
} catch (IOException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: so what should i do to fix it that they aren´t null?